# Using directX 11 in Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: directx-11

I want use include files

```
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
```

in visual studio 6.0.
But when i compile .cpp i we got this error:

```
:\Users\8up tuotlo\Desktop\Visual C++ 6.0 Proects\11\Article1\Article1.cpp(28) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'CD3D11_DEFAULT'
```

:\Users\8up tuotlo\Desktop\Visual C++ 6.0 Proects\11\Article1\Article1.cpp(28) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'CD3D11_DEFAULT'
When i include:

```
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
```

All normally compile.
What is this thing?

Comment: Be sure you have included the windows header files before the DirectX headers.

Answer (score 2):

Check the compiler support for recent versions of the Windows SDK. I suspect that VC++6 is no longer supported (it is over 15 years since it was released, with *six* releases since then).

Comment: It minds what i cannot use dx 11 libraries in Visual Studio 6.0?